# Adding an extra mailaccount in Android (manual setup disabled)

Tags: email

I'm trying to add another mailaccount (IMAP / SMTP).

However I cannot set it up.

- Applications
- Email
- Add account
- Fill in emailaddress and password
- I should be able to click on `Manual setup` now but it is grayed out (disabled).

I've also tried it without filling the emailaddress and password, but also without luck.

Android version 2.3.3

Any idea how to setup an extra mail account on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a gmail account (eg, myemail@gmail.com) or you haven't added the domain to the email address (eg,moo@cow.com), you cannot use manual setup.

Personally I would recommend ditching the native mail app and going with [K9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en) - it's a far superior email client.